# How to write test cases and test steps in redmine

Tags: testing, redmine, testcase, redmine-plugins

I am working at a company that uses Redmine as the issue tracking tool and for user stories.
I need to design the QA for them. However I didn't find a section where someone can tie a user story or an issue with a test case. I've used to have this functionality on Rally.
Is there a free tool that integrates with Redmine or something like a plugin?
I want the following (or the more the better!)

> - Description
> - test steps (input-output)
> - Status (pass-fail)
> - Suite name (the suite the test is part of)
> - Attached issues
> - Version of SW under test

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a "test case management" section in the [Redmine Third Party tools documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/ThirdPartyTools).

Comment: Well i checked the section you refer to, but none of them are free.

Comment: how about Testlink then? No perfect tool, but does the job. http://www.redmine.org/plugins/rp-testlinklink

Comment: it is a possibility thanks. please also view my response

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the support.A former colleague brought this to my attention:
https://bitbucket.org/bugzinga/redcase/wiki/Home

Comment: How is your experience with redcase? I am facing some issues in it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I often see is people trying to adapt tools to do things that they were not originally designed for. Redmine is a good tool for issue tracking and is designed mainly to be a project management tool, although it is possible to adapt redmine, I would suggest in this case looking for a dedicated test management tool that has been designed to do that specific job.

I would suggest looking at [TestLodge test management tool](http://www.testlodge.com) which I have worked on and is a designed to help you manage and execute your tests but at the same time integrates with Redmine and does things like automatically create tickets whenever a test fails.

By doing this, you are going to benefit from a range of things such as an interface designed for testing that will make you and your team a lot more productive along with a series of reports that will allow you to spot trends within your testing.